# Connect to CentOS LAMP instance from Windows PCs

Tags: windows, centos-6, lamp

I have a CentOS 6 machine running on our network which has a simple LAMP installation on it.

I have some files there which I would want to access through other Windows PC which I am able to do so using the IP address of the CentOS machine.

Since the IP address of the CentOS machine also could be dynamic I would want to connect to it using the computer / host name

But I am not able to do so using the computer / host name of the CentOS machine.

Can someone help me point out what I may be missing and help me out to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

SSH to server using the hostname.

[image: Putty]

- Open firewalls on both machines
- Check SE Status on Centos box.
- Open SSH access inside centos box.

Voila!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would like to access those files through the browser. SOmething like; http://centosmachine/folder/index.php. Apologies for not having mentioned that earlier

Comment: they you will have to setup a FTP on your centOS box... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-centos-6--2 Check this...